# Homomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi : G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a homomorphism of groups.

Now I have to prove that for any $g \in G_1$ we have  $\phi (g^{-1}) = [\phi (g)]^{-1}$.

So how should I begin?

Comment: Use the morphism property on the equation $g\cdot g^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: Use the definition of an inverse; $g^{-1}$ is an element in $G_1$ such that $gg^{-1} = 1$. Likewise $\phi(g)^{-1}$ is an element in $G_2$ such that $\phi(g)\phi(g)^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: The first step is to show that $\phi(1)=1$. Then use $\phi(g^{-1}g)=\phi(g^{-1})\phi(g)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** what's the defining property of an inverse? Can you use the properties of homomorphisms to show that $\phi(g^{-1})$ satisfies the relevant property?

Answer (score 4):

For any $g\in G$ we have $gg^{-1}=1=g^{-1}g$

For any homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow G'$ we have

$$\phi(g)\phi(g^{-1})=\phi(gg^{-1})=\phi(1)=1=\phi(1)=\phi(g^{-1}g)=\phi(g^{-1})\phi(g)$$

Comment: ...and, most importantly, $\phi(g)^{-1}$ is the **unique** element $x$ of $G_2$ such that $x\phi(g)=\phi(g)x=1$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : Yes.  agree